# ERROR in using python to read data from hbase through thrift

Tags: python, hbase, thrift

I am trying to read data from hbase use python. I installed thrift, and generated the gen-py files then moved it to the python lib:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

The hbase thrift server is in 192.168.15.116:39090. Is was started.

my code is in the server 192.168.15.146. In this machine, I can use hbase shell command to read the hbase data. 
Here is my Python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from thrift import Thrift                                                                                                                                                                
from thrift.transport import TSocket, TTransport                                                                                                                                         
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol                                                                                                                                              
from hbase import Hbase                                                                                                                                                                  


transport = TSocket.TSocket('192.168.15.116', 39090)                                                                                                                                     

transport.setTimeout(5000)                                                                                                                                                               

#transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)                                                                                                                                    

protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)                                                                                                                                    

client = Hbase.Client(protocol)                                                                                                                                                          

transport.open()                                                                                                                                                                         


print(client.getTableNames())
```

It was all ok but the last line, here is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test01.py", line 24, in <module>
    client.getTableNames()
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hbase/Hbase.py", line 788, in getTableNames
    return self.recv_getTableNames()
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hbase/Hbase.py", line 803, in recv_getTableNames
    raise x
thrift.Thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing getTableNames
```

I googled it but could'nt find the way to solve this ERRO, could anyone give me some help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but after having a quick look in the code it seems that the handler/processor code on the Server throws an unexpected exception. Unexpected meaning: neither a thrift one, nor one of the declared exceptions in the IDL file.

In that case the recommendation would be to look at HBase, whether this is a known issue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your thrift **host** and **Port**, you can use ***happybase***, example:

```py
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection(host='hadoop_env.com',port=9090,timeout=1000000)
connection.open()
print connection.tables()
```

There is another series of example:

https://github.com/Shadow-Hunter-X/python_practice_stepbystep/blob/master/python-on-bigdata/chapter6/chapter6_happybase.py

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29922173)